# Liferay persist Openstreetmap

Tags: liferay, openstreetmap, persist

I am using Liferay 7.3.7-ga8. To enable Openstreetmap, I can do it as the following:
Control Panel -> Instance Settings -> Third Party -> Maps -> Select Openstreetmap and Save.

However, I am trying to persist this configuration, so that when I rebuild Liferay, Openstreetmap option will be already enabled.

There are no additional information that I can find from [portal properties](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.3-ga8/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html). For other example (e.g. FontAwesome under System Settings), there is a menu where I can export the configuration. This is unfortunately not the case for Openstreetmap. Thx in advance for your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As this question is not programming-related (rather it's software configuration), please bring it over to the [Liferay community](https://liferay.dev), where it's on topic (see [help/on-topic])

Comment: Hi thx, I asked my question to the Liferay community. Should I then delete this thread? or is it ok to leave it. Thx

Comment: I've voted to close it here as it's off topic (stackoverflow focuses on programming-related questions only). For posting in multiple locations and keeping both open, please also [note the crossposting netiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824). So, if you ask me, I'd recommend deletion, yes.